# Spherical triangle side lengths

Tags: geometry

I have to solve an assignment question which deals a spherical triangle determined by the latitude/longitude coordinates A = (50, ­-41), B = (51, ­-41), and C = (51, ­-40). Does this mean AC = sqrt(2), BC = AB = 1 and angle(B) = 90 deg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the map with meridians and parallels, read about spherical trigonometry

The only true is `AB = 1`

Comment: Thank you @MBo. I did read about spherical trigonometry. Is AB=1, BC=0.88799, CA=1.3826 correct?

Comment: I think that great circle arc for BC is about (not exact) cos(51) ~ 0.63. angle(B) = 90.23'19'' (evaluated bearings here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html )